# d3.js 4.0 — Gridlines for linechart with centered axis

Tags: d3.js

I've started familiarizing myself with d3.js a few days ago. As luck would have it, the library underwent a major update a few weeks ago, and a lot of the existing resources are now out of date. I've managed to do most of what I had planned, but am now stuck on the "putting gridlines on it" part.

I've tried to use the "tick methods," to draw new lines, to search graphs with gridlines to see how they worked, etc. to no avail. Methods have changed names, and I don't always understand the documentation well, so it's a bit hard. I would really appreciate if someone could be so kind as to point me in the right direction. :)

I've put my code below to illustrate what I mean by "centered axis" (both are, actually).

```js
// Data
// Path data
var contractHighRange =    [
 { "x" : -6, "y" : 0.5 },
 { "x" : -5, "y" : 0.1 },
 { "x" : -4, "y" : 0.1 },
 { "x" : -2, "y" : 0.2 },
 { "x" : -1, "y" : 0.1 },
 { "x" : 0,  "y" : -0.1 },
 { "x" : 1,  "y" : -0.2 },
 { "x" : 2,  "y" : -0.1 },
 { "x" : 3,  "y" : -0.2 },
 { "x" : 4,  "y" : 0.2 },
 { "x" : 5,  "y" : 0.4 },
 { "x" : 6,  "y" : 0.5 }
];

var contractLowRange =    [
 { "x" : -6, "y" : 0.3 },
 { "x" : -5, "y" : -0.1 },
 { "x" : -4, "y" : -0.1 },
 { "x" : -2, "y" : 0 },
 { "x" : -1, "y" : -0.1 },
 { "x" : 0,  "y" : -0.3 },
 { "x" : 1,  "y" : -0.4 },
 { "x" : 2,  "y" : -0.3 },
 { "x" : 3,  "y" : -0.4 },
 { "x" : 4,  "y" : 0 },
 { "x" : 5,  "y" : 0.2 },
 { "x" : 6,  "y" : 0.3 }
];

var contractMiddleRange =    [
 { "x" : -6, "y" : 0.4 },
 { "x" : -5, "y" : 0 },
 { "x" : -4, "y" : 0 },
 { "x" : -2, "y" : 0.1 },
 { "x" : -1, "y" : 0 },
 { "x" : 0,  "y" : -0.2 },
 { "x" : 1,  "y" : -0.3 },
 { "x" : 2,  "y" : -0.2 },
 { "x" : 3,  "y" : -0.3 },
 { "x" : 4,  "y" : 0.1 },
 { "x" : 5,  "y" : 0.3 },
 { "x" : 6,  "y" : 0.4 }
];

// Axis definition
var contractInformationForAxis = [
 { "name" : "abscissa",      "x" : -6,    "y" : 6},
 { "name" : "ordinate",      "x" : -0.8,  "y" : 0.8}
];

var contractInformationForScatterpoints = [
 { "name" : "qM",       "x" : -5.25,    "y" : 0.1 },
 { "name" : "uM",       "x" : 5,        "y" : -3.5 },
 { "name" : "uSMi",     "x" : -2.75,    "y" : 0 },
 { "name" : "uSMa",     "x" :  3.75,    "y" : 0 }
];

// General appearance
var margin = { top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50 };
var width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Main SVG
var svgContainer =
 d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Axis creation
var xAxisScale =
 d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([
   contractInformationForAxis[0].x,
   contractInformationForAxis[0].y])
  .range([0, width]);

var yAxisScale =
 d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([
   contractInformationForAxis[1].x,
   contractInformationForAxis[1].y])
  .range([height, 0]);

// Axis generation
var xAxisGroup =
 svgContainer
  .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height / 2) + ")")
   .call(d3.axisBottom(xAxisScale));

var yAxisGroup =
 svgContainer
  .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + ", 0)")
   .call(d3.axisLeft(yAxisScale));

// Noms des axes
var xAxisName =
 svgContainer
 .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + " ," + (height + margin.top) + ")")
  .attr("class", "xAxisName")
  .text("xAxis");

var yAxisName =
 svgContainer
 .append("text")
  .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
  .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
  .attr("dy", "1em")
  .attr("class", "yAxisName")
  .text("yAxis");

// Lines creation
var lineFunction =
 d3.line()
  .x(function(d) { return xAxisScale(d.x); })
  .y(function(d) { return yAxisScale(d.y); })
  .curve(d3.curveLinear);

// Lines generation
var contractHighRangePath =
 svgContainer
  .append("path")
   .attr("d", lineFunction(contractHighRange))
   .attr("class", "lineHighRange");

var contractLowRangePath =
 svgContainer
  .append("path")
   .attr("d", lineFunction(contractLowRange))
   .attr("class", "lineLowRange");

var contractMiddleRangePath =
 svgContainer
  .append("path")
   .attr("d", lineFunction(contractMiddleRange))
   .attr("class", "lineMiddleRange");

// SCATTERPOINTS
var contractPointsCreation =
 svgContainer
  .selectAll("dot")
  .data(contractInformationForScatterpoints)
  .enter()
  .append("g");

// Generate scatterplots
var contractPointsGeneration =
 contractPointsCreation
  .append("circle")
   .attr("r", 10)
   .attr("cx", function(d) { return xAxisScale(d.x); })
   .attr("cy", function(d) { return yAxisScale(d.y); })
   .attr("class", "exteriorCircle");

var contractPointsText =
 contractPointsCreation
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(contractInformationForScatterpoints)
  .enter();

var contractPointsTextAttributes =
 contractPointsText
  .append("text")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return xAxisScale(d.x); })
   .attr("y", function(d) { return yAxisScale(d.y) + margin.top / 2.5; })
   .attr("class", "contractPointsText")
   .text(function(d) { return "(" + d.name + " " + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")"});
```

```css
h1 {
  color: darkgreen;
}

.lineHighRange {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.lineLowRange {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.lineMiddleRange {
  fill: none;
  stroke: orange;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.exteriorCircle {
  fill: darkred;
}

.contractPointsText{
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.yAxisName {
  text-anchor: middle;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.xAxisName {
  text-anchor: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<title>Linechart</title>


<body>

  <h1>Demo - d3 4.0</h1>

  <script src="js/chart.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing D3 axis ticks, we can append lines to each tick.

First, we set classes to each axis (`xAxis` and `yAxis`). Then, we select the ticks(`d3.selectAll("g.yAxis g.tick")` and `d3.selectAll("g.xAxis g.tick")`) of each axis and append a line to each tick.

I set a class "gridline" to these lines. Use the CSS to change their opacity, color, style etc.

Check the snippet below.

```js
// Data
// Path data
var contractHighRange =    [
 { "x" : -6, "y" : 0.5 },
 { "x" : -5, "y" : 0.1 },
 { "x" : -4, "y" : 0.1 },
 { "x" : -2, "y" : 0.2 },
 { "x" : -1, "y" : 0.1 },
 { "x" : 0,  "y" : -0.1 },
 { "x" : 1,  "y" : -0.2 },
 { "x" : 2,  "y" : -0.1 },
 { "x" : 3,  "y" : -0.2 },
 { "x" : 4,  "y" : 0.2 },
 { "x" : 5,  "y" : 0.4 },
 { "x" : 6,  "y" : 0.5 }
];

var contractLowRange =    [
 { "x" : -6, "y" : 0.3 },
 { "x" : -5, "y" : -0.1 },
 { "x" : -4, "y" : -0.1 },
 { "x" : -2, "y" : 0 },
 { "x" : -1, "y" : -0.1 },
 { "x" : 0,  "y" : -0.3 },
 { "x" : 1,  "y" : -0.4 },
 { "x" : 2,  "y" : -0.3 },
 { "x" : 3,  "y" : -0.4 },
 { "x" : 4,  "y" : 0 },
 { "x" : 5,  "y" : 0.2 },
 { "x" : 6,  "y" : 0.3 }
];

var contractMiddleRange =    [
 { "x" : -6, "y" : 0.4 },
 { "x" : -5, "y" : 0 },
 { "x" : -4, "y" : 0 },
 { "x" : -2, "y" : 0.1 },
 { "x" : -1, "y" : 0 },
 { "x" : 0,  "y" : -0.2 },
 { "x" : 1,  "y" : -0.3 },
 { "x" : 2,  "y" : -0.2 },
 { "x" : 3,  "y" : -0.3 },
 { "x" : 4,  "y" : 0.1 },
 { "x" : 5,  "y" : 0.3 },
 { "x" : 6,  "y" : 0.4 }
];

// Axis definition
var contractInformationForAxis = [
 { "name" : "abscissa",      "x" : -6,    "y" : 6},
 { "name" : "ordinate",      "x" : -0.8,  "y" : 0.8}
];

var contractInformationForScatterpoints = [
 { "name" : "qM",       "x" : -5.25,    "y" : 0.1 },
 { "name" : "uM",       "x" : 5,        "y" : -3.5 },
 { "name" : "uSMi",     "x" : -2.75,    "y" : 0 },
 { "name" : "uSMa",     "x" :  3.75,    "y" : 0 }
];

// General appearance
var margin = { top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50 };
var width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Main SVG
var svgContainer =
 d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Axis creation
var xAxisScale =
 d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([
   contractInformationForAxis[0].x,
   contractInformationForAxis[0].y])
  .range([0, width]);

var yAxisScale =
 d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([
   contractInformationForAxis[1].x,
   contractInformationForAxis[1].y])
  .range([height, 0]);

// Axis generation
var xAxisGroup =
 svgContainer
  .append("g")
        .attr("class", "xAxis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height / 2) + ")")
   .call(d3.axisBottom(xAxisScale));

var yAxisGroup =
 svgContainer
  .append("g")
        .attr("class", "yAxis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + ", 0)")
   .call(d3.axisLeft(yAxisScale));

 d3.selectAll("g.yAxis g.tick") 
        .append("line") 
            .attr("class", "gridline")
            .attr("x1", -(width/2)) 
            .attr("y1", 0)
            .attr("x2", width/2)
            .attr("y2", 0);
            
         d3.selectAll("g.xAxis g.tick") 
        .append("line") 
            .attr("class", "gridline")
            .attr("x1", 0) 
            .attr("y1", height/2)
            .attr("x2", 0)
            .attr("y2", -height/2);

// Noms des axes
var xAxisName =
 svgContainer
 .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + " ," + (height + margin.top) + ")")
  .attr("class", "xAxisName")
  .text("xAxis");

var yAxisName =
 svgContainer
 .append("text")
  .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
  .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
  .attr("dy", "1em")
  .attr("class", "yAxisName")
  .text("yAxis");

// Lines creation
var lineFunction =
 d3.line()
  .x(function(d) { return xAxisScale(d.x); })
  .y(function(d) { return yAxisScale(d.y); })
  .curve(d3.curveLinear);

// Lines generation
var contractHighRangePath =
 svgContainer
  .append("path")
   .attr("d", lineFunction(contractHighRange))
   .attr("class", "lineHighRange");

var contractLowRangePath =
 svgContainer
  .append("path")
   .attr("d", lineFunction(contractLowRange))
   .attr("class", "lineLowRange");

var contractMiddleRangePath =
 svgContainer
  .append("path")
   .attr("d", lineFunction(contractMiddleRange))
   .attr("class", "lineMiddleRange");

// SCATTERPOINTS
var contractPointsCreation =
 svgContainer
  .selectAll("dot")
  .data(contractInformationForScatterpoints)
  .enter()
  .append("g");

// Generate scatterplots
var contractPointsGeneration =
 contractPointsCreation
  .append("circle")
   .attr("r", 10)
   .attr("cx", function(d) { return xAxisScale(d.x); })
   .attr("cy", function(d) { return yAxisScale(d.y); })
   .attr("class", "exteriorCircle");

var contractPointsText =
 contractPointsCreation
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(contractInformationForScatterpoints)
  .enter();

var contractPointsTextAttributes =
 contractPointsText
  .append("text")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return xAxisScale(d.x); })
   .attr("y", function(d) { return yAxisScale(d.y) + margin.top / 2.5; })
   .attr("class", "contractPointsText")
   .text(function(d) { return "(" + d.name + " " + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")"});
```

```css
h1 {
  color: darkgreen;
}

.lineHighRange {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.lineLowRange {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.lineMiddleRange {
  fill: none;
  stroke: orange;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.exteriorCircle {
  fill: darkred;
}

.contractPointsText{
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.yAxisName {
  text-anchor: middle;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.xAxisName {
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.gridline{
stroke: black;
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
stroke-opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<title>Linechart</title>


<body>

  <h1>Demo - d3 4.0</h1>

  <script src="js/chart.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just tested it—and it works very well! Nice implementation, I find it very clean. Thank you! :)