# D3 V4 ticks line x1 value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So here's the scenario:

I set xAxis: `axisLeft().tickSize(-width)`, same for the yAxis, this makes a grid out of axis:

[image]

Is it possible to make a grid out of tick lines and at the same time make them point at tick values like this?

[image]

(in this example I set manualy x1 value to the tick line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have both the ticks going inside and outside using `tickSize`. A positive value will make the ticks grow outside, and a negative value will make the ticks grow inside the plotting area.

But there are different ways to have both inside and outside ticks. My favourite one is creating a separate set of lines (the gridline) without using the axis generator (see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38329969/5768908). This is more complicated but has the advantage of allowing you to set them a different colour, stroke-width, opacity etc.

A simpler approach, that doesn't allow such customisations, is translating the ticks to the left. In this demo, I'm setting the `tickSize`:

```
.tickSize(width + someValue)
```

And then moving them to the left:

```
.attr("transform", "translate(-someValue, 0)");
```

Check the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
var data = d3.range(10);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,10]).range([140,10]);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickSize(-256).tickPadding(10);
var gY = svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").attr("transform", "translate(50,0)").call(yAxis);
d3.selectAll(".y.axis .tick line").attr("transform", "translate(-6,0)");
```

```css
.y.axis .tick line{
 stroke: #999
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hoped that there's an official way of doing this nicely but...not yet I guess.
Thanks for the answer and example, I'll keep things simple for now and use the translate on the tick line as there's no need for a more complicated separate grid elements for now.

Comment: Also if the simplest solution for now is to use translate on the tick line a cleaner way would be just to set the outside value on x1 attribute instead of translate, this way you don't have to add the outside width of the tick line in to the width.

Comment: The problem is you can't explicitly set the "x1" position in the axis generator. The "x1" of the tick is over the axis line, and the "x2" depends on the value of `tickSize` (inwards or outwards).

Comment: I meant setting it just like translate, like this:
`d3.selectAll(".y.axis .tick line").attr("x1", "-6");` Sorry for confusion